# Limit attributes in GE kml pop-up box to only those present

Tags: kml

Searching for this answer has been unsuccessful.  I have a kml created from a shapefile.  It contains 49 attributes.  Not all attributes occur within every polygon.  If an attribute occurs in a polygon the attribute pop-up box will list all 49 attributes and place an “X” beside those that are present (see link).  Is there a way for the pop-up list to only display a list of the attributes that are present in the selected polygon?

[image: picture of pop-up box list with all the attributes]

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is how the particular shape to KML converter works. The description element for each placemark is being generated with X's. Either need to post-process the KML file with a script or need to write a custom shape to KML converter.

There are libraries such as GIScore that can read KML files, manipulate the contents then write them back to a new file. [GIScore](https://github.com/OpenSextant/giscore) and [JAK](https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml) are Java libraries that can both do that. GIScore can also read a shape file and output a KML file, but you would need to populate the description contents with custom code. The [GIScore wiki](https://github.com/OpenSextant/giscore/wiki#Reading_KML) provides an example to parse a KML file. It's simple enough to create a KMLOuputStream and write out each feature as it is read.

```
KmlInputStream kis = new KmlInputStream(...);
KmlOututStream kos = new KmlOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("new.kml"));
for (IGISObject gisObj; (gisObj = kis.read()) != null; ) {
  if (gisObj instanceof Feature) {
    Feature f = (Feature)gisObj;
    String desc = f.getDescription();
    // TODO: re-create description and remove empty fields
    f.setDescription(desc);
  }
  // write each feature to new KML file in same order of original file
  kos.write(gisObj);
}
kos.close();
kis.close);
```